# extjs validation error message formatting

Tags: css, extjs

I have the following code snippet

```
{
    fieldLabel : 'Types',
    xtype : 'radiogroup',
    width : 250,
    height: 75,
    vertical : false,
    allowBlank : false,
    msgTarget : 'under',
    blankText : 'test',,
    labelAlign: 'top',
    itemId: 'typeCd',
    id: 'typeCode',
    beforeLabelTextTpl : ''
    ...
}
```

So this is basically a radio button pair like a Yes/No. There are 2 radio buttons and it's a required field. If nothing is selected, I am displaying an error message in red.

The issue i'm seeing here is that the error message appears under the radio button group but it comes right at the bottom of the span/div. Like, for instance, if I change the height here from 75 to 250, the height of the span/div increases but the error message still sticks to the bottom of that panel. I want the error message to show right underneath the radio button group and I am not sure how to format/style it in such a way that I see that behavior.

Comment: It works for me. Could you change the following fiddle, so that it shows the wrong formatting.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/323n

Comment: that is exactly how I want it to work but in my code, it appears like I have 2 newlines in between the radio group and the validation message. anything else I can check to see what the issue could be? maybe stylesheets specific to the app?

Comment: the only thing I could think of is `layout`. if you use `layout: 'form',` on the formpanel, it would kill the position. I add it to the fiddle.